# CakePHP doesn't redirect properly

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cakephp-routing

I've just finished the Getting started tutorial (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html) and put my files on an Apache server, that has Drupal projet as root URL.

The Cakephp's index page loads fine, but when I click on any item, changing my root url to something like `root/posts/view/2`, it displays Drupal's *page not found* error.

I guess it may be a rewrite problem. My CakePHP directory has an .htaccess file containing :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And my apache2 sites-enabled conf ends with :

```
Alias /test /var/www/cakephp/app/webroot
<Directory /var/www/cakephp/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I change the index action route from :

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
```

to :

```
Router::connect('/foo', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
```

I've got the same error as described above.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem came from Rewrite mod. Removing the 3 .htaccess files allowed me to access the app urls.

By the way, I tried on a fresh clean Apache server with the following .htaccess files and it worked :

**/var/www/cakephp/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /cakephp/
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/var/www/cakephp/app/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /cakephp/app/
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/var/www/cakephp/app/webroot/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /cakephp/app/webroot/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```